# Python - Retrieve and replace based on a regex

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Basically I've imported a csv of about 17000 rows into a pandas dataframe. There is a date column that has been imported as `int64` because data quality is very poor. Examples of dates include `11969`, `12132001`, `1022013`, etc. So I figure what I want to do is retrieve just the last 4 numbers from the date column.

So the code I've used is:

```
test_str = str(df['Date'])
flags = re.MULTILINE
p = r'\d{4}$'
result = re.findall(p, test_str, flags)
```

When I `print(result)` only 60 of the 17000 values are returned. I'm assuming it only assess uniques, but after a long bout of googling I can't figure it out.  Any ideas on how I can work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your method actually does work (at least for the examples you gave):

```
import pandas as pd
rng = pd.Series([11969, 12132001, 1022013, 1022013])
test_str = str(rng)
flags = re.MULTILINE
p = r'\d{4}$'
result = re.findall(p, test_str, flags)
print(result)
# ['1969', '2001', '2013', '2013'] # not just unique values
```

But this method of converting a `pandas` series into a string is a bizarre way of doing it and doesn't take advantage of `pandas` inherent structure.

You might consider doing this:

```
df['year_int'] = df['Date'] % 10000
```

to get the last four digits if `df['Date']` is `int64`. Or this:

```
df['year_str'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[-4:])
```

if you'd rather convert to a string and then take the last four characters.

```
print(df)
#        Date  year_int year_str
# 0     11969      1969     1969
# 1  12132001      2001     2001
# 2   1022013      2013     2013
# 3   1022013      2013     2013
```

Comment: Thanks so much -- Your alternative ways worked.

And yeah I know with a sample/small data set my regex way worked.. Its just i'd only get returned 60 out of 17000 rows. As you said, I must be doing something weird with pandas. Should look into that a bit more.